# How do I fix this small (and probably simple) DirectoryInfo Syntax error?

Tags: c#, system.io.directory

Pretty straight forward. Press a button, select a path from dialogbox, searches path's subdirectories, and shows them in messagebox. But have ran into a couple problems.

```
private void InputButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    //CHECKS TO SEE IF "OK" WAS CLICKED IN DIALOGBOX
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {

    }

    //SELECTS DIRECTORY PATH
    Path.GetDirectoryName(fbd.SelectedPath);
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fbd.SelectedPath);
    InputDirectory_Box.Text = path;

    //SELECTS SUBDIRECTORIES FROM PATH
    string[] subdirectories = DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories(path);
    for (int i = 0; subdirectories.Length+1 >= 0; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(subdirectories[i]);
    }


}
```

The line `string[] subdirectories = DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories(path);` says it needs an object reference for the non-static field. I've already declared `path` to give it the string to search. I used this exact same line of code and syntax for the Directory class (not the `DirectoryInfo` class) and it was legal. However, i was having a problem when using `Directory.GetDirectories`. It was finding the path's *parent* directories instead of the `subdirectories` for some reason.

If anyone could shine some light on:
A - why I'm getting this syntax error
B - why it was returning parent directories instead of sub-directories from the path

Then you would be a hero. Many thanks

PS I'm completely new to programming and don't know what enumerating/enumeration is quite yet so if it has something to do with that, I'd appreciate maybe a small example or some context of what it is.

Answer (score 1):

[GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58(v=vs.110).aspx) is an instance method. You need to have an instance of `DirectoryInfo` to use it.

```
string path = fbd.SelectedPath;

// Make a reference to a directory.
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

// Get a reference to each directory in that directory.
string[] subdirectories = di.GetDirectories();
```

Answer (score 0):

The static class would be [Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```

The first of those two lines is useless...

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(fbd.SelectedPath);
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fbd.SelectedPath);
```

Next thing: I do not understand that loop... what do you want to achieve with `Length+1>=0`?
To print out all directories of any list/array you have two choices: A `for` loop, or even better if you don't need the index of the items, a `foreach` loop.

Look at these examples:

```
   string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
    for (int i = 0; i < subdirectories.Length; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(subdirectories[i]);
    }

   string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
    foreach (string directory in subdirectories)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(directory);
    }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: While reading, I learned you can index an array backwards from end to start with length-1. I figured that length+1 would be the start of the array.

The rewrite of the code is helpful thank you. However, I'm also trying to figure out how to use the DirectoryInfo class. More specifically, the DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories, which is different than the Directories class. I think someone else answered this though. It needs to be instantiated.